# Ajax request piling up on consecutive actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

**Context:** I'm implementing a form in modal. Both form opening and form submitting are ajax requests.

So my code works like the following:

1. From home page, on clicking a button "Edit Details", I'm fetching Edit Details form via ajax, and showing this on modal.
2. I also have javascript code which fills the default details on the form, and also "Submit" via ajax code, this code is defined at the bottom of the modal jsp which I was fetching in ajax request in step 1.
3. There's a complete_invoices button on modal, which fires an ajax to save details/ show error.

The Issue I'm facing  is that the number of ajax calls to **"Submit"** from modal increases linearly.

So say,

I open **"Edit Details"** first time, **"Submit"**, ajax call - 1

Second time **"Edit Details"** from the same home page, **"Submit"**, number of ajax calls goes are - 2

and so on, this goes on increasing by 1.

What I'm suspecting is that browser caches the **javascript** code which is coming by **"Edit Details"** modal. And on consecutive times, now browser has two actions to fire on same **"Submit"** button. Is that so?

How do I get around this behavior?

Comment: Sounds like you are adding event listeners more than once, likely on each ajax call. Use event delegation instead. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You can put your ajax functions code on main page, so that code load only once when page loads, then play with modal with add / edit details